# Config logging on which cisco IOS?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, logging

I want to configure configuration logging on network devices by running following commands.

```
archive
log config
logging enable
```

I want to know which Cisco IOS and device support it?

I used cisco feature navigator but did not get the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost every Cisco IOS router 12.x and 15.x supports this command.
You can use it in this way to send configuration command logging to syslog server:

```
conf terminal
archive
 log config
  logging enable
  logging size 200
  notify syslog contenttype plaintext
  hidekeys
logging xx.xx.xx.xx
```

where *xx.xx.xx.xx* - your syslog-server.

Also you can view previous configuration commands that were applied to this router by running `show archive log config all`. You must know, that this command display history data only from last reboot. That's why it's recommended to save configuration command history in syslog.

Also FYI:

> Feature name - Configuration Change Notification and Logging
>
> Releases - 12.2(25)S, 12.2(27)SBC, 12.2(33)SB, 12.2(33)SRA,
>   12.2(33)SXH, 12.3(4)T, 15.0(1)EX, Cisco IOS XE Release 2.1
>
> Feature info: 
>   The Configuration Change Notification and Logging (Configuration
>   Logging) feature allows the tracking of configuration changes entered
>   on a per-session and per-user basis by implementing a configuration
>   log. The configuration log tracks each configuration command that is
>   applied, who applied the command, the parser return code for the
>   command, and the time the command was applied. This feature also adds
>   a notification mechanism that sends asynchronous notifications to
>   registered applications whenever the configuration log changes.
>
> The following commands were introduced or modified: archive, hidekeys,
>   log config, logging enable, logging size, notify syslog, show archive
>   log config.